# Multiplying a Matrix with its Transpose

Tags: c, matrix

Currently, I am in the process of optimizing a program that takes a ***n x n*** matrix and multiplies it with its **transpose**. I am trying to optimize my matrix calculation algorithm so that it completes in as few clock cycles as possible.

Here is my pseudo code attempt at creating an optimised algorithm.

```
// Matrix Multiplicaiton B = A*A'
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        temp = 0;
        n_times_i = n * i;

        for (int k = 0; k < (n*n); k+=n)
        {
            temp += A[j + k] * A[i + k];
        }

        B[j + n_times_i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see any way that I might be able to further improve upon my algorithm here?

Comment: Throw all of this out and use BLAS instead? is there a reason you aren't calling into that or LAPACK?

Comment: It's hard to review a small fragment out of context.  Please show the full function, including any user-defined types you need.  A great question would also include your test suite, so we can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barring any compiler heroics, you are computing `n*n` a total of \$n^3\$ times.  You might want to cache that result.

```
const int nn = n*n;
```

---

`B[j + n_times_i]` is a linearly increasing address location, given that `j` increases by 1 for each middle loop, and and `i` increases once for each outer loop, which is `n` increases of `j`.  Taking advantage of that, you can skip the `j + n*i` calculation, and `B[ ]` indexing.

```
int *pB  = &B;
// ... loops & calculation of temp omitted for brevity.
      *pB++ = temp;
```

---

Result:

```
const int nn = n*n;
int *pB = B;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        temp = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < nn; k += n) {
            temp += A[i+k] * A[j+k];
        }
        *pB++ = temp;
    }
}
```

---

You *may* find that you can get additional speed by using pointer arithmetic for `A[i+k]` and `A[j+k]`.

```
int *pAi = A + i;
int *pAj = A + j;
for (k=0; k<n; k++) {   // Note: n.  The nn variable is no longer needed.
    temp += *pAi * *pAj;
    pAi += n;
    pAj += n;
}
```

But, you’ll need to profile to find out.  It depends on the number of free registers you have ... and the compiler/optimizers these days are pretty darn good.

Comment: "*compiler heroics*" is quite a strong term for a very simple optimisation (even if we don't declare `n` as constant, all optimisers will spot it's unmodified and re-use the expression result).

Comment: @TobySpeight Shh!  They might hear you.  They are subtle and quick to anger, and I appreciate all heroics efforts they make on my behalf, big and small, and dare not anger them in any way, for without them I would be forced to wrestle with the dreaded realm and the demons of assembly, ARM, Thumb, MIPS and the brethren of x86, and the pony ... he comes!

Comment: @TobySpeight, thanks so much for your help on the solution above. Quick question for you - What might the pointer arithmetic for *pAi and *pAj look like in MIPS assembly?